# "like" in spoken English

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality-in-context, spoken-english

How good and correct is it to use "like" in spoken English in such a way?

I mean the ones like:

> - "I was like - hey, bring me a coffee - and she was like - you go get it yourself - and then James came in and it was like - wtf is going on in 'ere?"

Comment: It's informal and colloquial. You'd happily use it in a text, you wouldn't use it in a formal report.

Comment: Sometimes this isn’t so much a matter of “good and correct” as it is a matter of [overused to the point of being annoying](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=using+like+too+often). @user8543 - I wouldn’t encourage its use “happily" in a text; it seems more of a verbal construct than a written one.

Comment: @j.r. I have a lot of text conversations in various formats - _like_ is used prodigiously and effectively (if, as you say, sometimes annoyingly).

Comment: @user8543 - I just didn’t want a learner to read your initial comment, and conclude that, like, they should start sprinkling it all over their text messages.  ;-)

Comment: @j.r. that's, like, just your opinion, man ;)

Comment: @J.R. Well as a person who stumbles upon such probabilities occasionally I would like to know if and when is it possible to do such things.

Comment: Back out of the room slowly, and do not talk to them ever again. If they're your friends, make new friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That usage was once laughed at as being a caricature of a certain small southern-California subculture of shallow, dim, over-privileged teen-aged girls, the "Valley Girls".  Then, as its use spread via television, it lost that particular subcultural connection.

The people who talk like that are generally not respected very much.

Comment: Can I use it written English in a conversation between two characters?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Make the characters young and socioeconomically low in the working class.

Comment: Typically this was an upper class thing in the early 90s, and it seems to have bled out into the tech sector. Quite bizarre. Even seeing it with guys.